# What is the origin of the term "nose bleed" section?

Tags: etymology, expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the reason for calling cheap seats at the theatre nosebleed seats?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/whats-the-reason-for-calling-cheap-seats-at-the-theatre-nosebleed-seats)

When referring to the section of the stadium farthest from the stage/field, it is not uncommon to call it the "nose bleed section."  Where does this term come from?